# HTML CSS Use wrapper to add caption to image gallery

Tags: html, css, image, gallery

I have a very simple image gallery.

The height of the images is controlled by a div call 'row'. I would like to add a unique caption below each of the images.

The caption should be the same width as the image it relates to (the image width changes according to the screen ratio and size).

This seems so infuriatingly simple, but I just can't work it out. Thanks in advance.

Here's what I have...

https://codepen.io/GBol/pen/yLRMOdY

```css
.row {
  width: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 11 / 2;
  display: block;
  border: solid purple;
}

.pic {
  height: 90%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0% 1% 0% 0%;
  display: block;
  border: solid red;
}

.caption {
  display: block;
  font-size: 10pt;
  width: 100%;
  border: solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <a href="http://placekitten.com/500/600">
    <img class="pic" src="http://placekitten.com/500/600" />
  </a>
  <a href="http://placekitten.com/300/600">
    <img class="pic" src="http://placekitten.com/300/600" />
  </a>
  <a href="http://placekitten.com/400/600">
    <img class="pic" src="http://placekitten.com/400/600" />
  </a>
</div>

<div class="caption">
  Caption Example
</div>
```

I tried using another div as a wrapper to join the images and the caption, but can't get this to work correctly.

Comment: Are you able to adjust your HTML, I'd suggest that a [`<figure>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure) - with a child [`<figcaption>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figcaption) - might be a better fit for what you're doing, and would make it far easier to align the captions with the relevant images.

Comment: Further to my previous comment, an example: https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/oz8293ct/

Comment: @David Thanks so much for this solution. In my original post, the height of the images is the same, then the widths are adjusted accordingly, this is my aim. Is there a way to do this with your method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done using simple display flex containers and row-column flex direction.

I have added codepen solution here https://codepen.io/abhijeetabnave/pen/xxyqOoy

```css
.row {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  aspect-ratio: 11 / 2;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: solid purple;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.pic {
  height: 90%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0% 1% 0% 0%;
  display: block;
  border: solid red;
}

.caption {
  display: block;
  font-size: 10pt;
  width: 100%;
  border: solid blue;
}

.image-container {
  height: 90%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <a href="http://placekitten.com/500/600">
    <div class="image-container" ><img class="pic" src="http://placekitten.com/500/600" />
      <span> 
       <div class="caption">
         Caption Example 1
       </div>
      </span>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="http://placekitten.com/300/600">
    <div class="image-container" ><img class="pic" src="http://placekitten.com/300/600" />
      <span>
        <div class="caption">
          Caption Example 2
        </div>
      </span>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="http://placekitten.com/400/600">
    <div class="image-container" ><img class="pic" src="http://placekitten.com/400/600" />
      <span>
        <div class="caption">
          Caption Example 3
        </div>
      </span>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: please see this codepen. Currently the caption is stretching the image, is there a way to prevent this? It would be great if the caption started a new line rather than exceed the width of the image. https://codepen.io/GBol/pen/abRJmyx